"Variable not allowed in type expression" - how can I create parameterized typing.Annotated types?
I'm not sure if this is possible in Python, but I'd like to create a series of related typing.Annotated referring to the same underlying type, but where each is constrained to a different set of values (ideally using enums, but that isn't crucial), and annotated with metadata about what it accepts. I could manually specify them all, but it would be cleaner if this could be parameterized.
Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum
from typing import Annotated

from annotated_types import Predicate

class WildAnimals(Enum):
    LION = 'lion'
    BEAR = 'bear'

class PetAnimals(Enum):
    CAT = 'cat'
    DOG = 'dog'

def ConstrainedType(allowed_values: type[Enum]):
    return Annotated[
        str,
        Predicate(lambda val: val in (m.value for m in allowed_values)),
        f'Allowed: {list(allowed_values)}',
    ]

def ConstrainedContainer(allowed_values: type[Enum]):

    CType = ConstrainedType(allowed_values)

    @dataclass
    class Container:
        # error: Variable not allowed in type expression (reportInvalidTypeForm)
        animal: CType
        count: int

    return Container

PetCarrier = ConstrainedContainer(PetAnimals)
WildCarrier = ConstrainedContainer(WildAnimals)

As far as I can tell, this code runs fine (as it should, since type hints are optional) but Pyright objects to line 29 where I'm assigning CType as a type for animal:

example.py:29:17 - error: Variable not allowed in type expression (reportInvalidTypeForm)

If I instead try to inline ConstrainedType() I get this error:

example.py:29:17 - error: Call expression not allowed in type expression (reportInvalidTypeForm)

What am I missing here? Do I need to be using TypeVar or Generic somehow? Is there a way to have parameterized types that aren't "variable" so the type checker can understand them?

Dynamically added annotations and classes may work for runtime type checkers like Pydantic, but not static ones like Mypy and Pyright. It is simply not possible for them to determine all these values without running your code. For this specific case, perhaps what you want is Literal: Literal['lion', 'cat']/Literal[PetAnimals, WildAnimals].

Since I know that ConstrainedType() always returns a type[Annotated] - can I explicitly tag it somewhere to tell the static type checkers that's what it is? Literals would be a good option if my real use-case involved strings. I'm actually trying to constrain the units for Astropy quantities but I was trying to write this question to address the general problem.

There's this proposal, but even that doesn't allow you to specify Annotated alone as a form. Besides, static type checkers (generally) ignore all metadata anyway.

Yeah, that's another thing that's a bit frustrating to me: I can understand why static type checkers can't deal with fully dynamic types defined at runtime, but I'm really talking about parameterizing Annotated to attach metadata, so you might think Pyright/mypy could ignore that completely and still "see" that the underlying type is unchanged. I'm wondering if there's a way to cheat around this using typing.NewType() but I'm also about to give up and go for the full copy-paste approach.

...or you could write a code generator to do the copy-pasting for you, as a compromise. NewType only ever creates virtual subtypes at type checking time, so I doubt it would be possible to make a solution out of it.

What about typing.TypeAliasTypes? Are those first class objects that can have distinct metadata Annotated on them?

TypeAliasType is the type of runtime constructs created by type statements (e.g. type Foo = int | str; assert isinstance(Foo, TypeAliasType)). I will stop responding further, since this is about to get off-topic.
